# A spaceship is traveling (left to right) along the curve y=3cosx.

Tags: derivatives

An object is released from the spaceship at x= pi/3 and travels along a line tangent to the graph of y=3cosx towards the x-axis.

a) At what point x will the object strike the x axis?

b) At what angle theta will the object strike the x axis?

I don't even know how to start on this one!

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating $3\cos(x)$ and substituting $\frac{\pi}{3}$ will give you the slope of the tangent line at this point. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I understand that, but why do I need the slope of the tangent line?

Comment: Using the slope, you can immediately obtain the angle $\theta$ (just plug it into the arctangent function), solving b), and also set up a linear equation which will give you the answer to a).

Comment: okay so i got the slope to be (-3(3)^1/2)/(2) and why do I plug it to arctangent? is it because it's a tangent line slope?

Comment: @Kaaagome: The arctangent function is the inverse of the tangent function. The tangent function of an angle gives the slope, so the arctangent function of a slope gives the angle.

Comment: oh! i didn't realize that! thank you! the linear equation is just the slope, the x, and the y, right? thank you so much again!

Comment: @Kaaagome: That's right, $ax+y$, where $a$ is the slope.